# Filter Completion Suggester With AND instead of OR

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am trying to filter Completion Suggestion results based on the completion contexts I have setup in my mapping. Here is a sample query.

```
POST jekyll/_suggest?pretty
{
    "title-author-suggestion" : {
        "prefix" : "Donald",
        "completion" : {
            "field" : "Suggest",
            "contexts" : {
              "Tags" : "general",
              "Authors" : "Katie Reilly"
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am running into is that results seem to be filtering with an **OR** effect, rather than an **AND** effect.

For example, imagine I have these two documents.

```
{
    "Title" : "Donald Duck is amazing",
    "Tags" : [ "general" ],
    "Authors" : [ "Bob" ]
}

{
    "Title" : "Donald Trump is president, whaaaat?!",
    "Tags" : [ "general" ],
    "Authors" : [ "Katie Reilly" ]
}
```

I would imagine that running a completion suggestion query, like the one at the top of my question, would give me a result of 1 document.

```
{
    "Title" : "Donal Duck is amazing",
    "Tags" : [ "general" ],
    "Authors" : [ "Katie Reilly" ]
}
```

Instead, I get both documents.

**Is there a way to change the behavior on a Completion suggestion query to exhibit the behavior I expect or do I just have to not use the Completion suggestion?**

Comment: You seem to be running into [issue #21291](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21291) which is still open. Maybe you should +1 and comment so it gets back on their radar.

Comment: Thank you Val, at least I know now that I'm not crazy.... or am I? :)

Comment: Still not fixed? Or is it? Stuck on v2 until fixed :O